# Update existing content using migrate module

Tags: migrations

I'm using migrate module in Drupal 7 to update existing content of a Drupal site. My source and destination tables are the same. I got some documentation from http://drupal.org/node/1117454. Here's my code:

```
<?php
class MTestMigration extends Migration {

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->systemOfRecord = Migration::DESTINATION;
    $this->team = array(
      new MigrateTeamMember('foo', 'foo@bar.com', t('Site builder')),
    );

    $this->description = t('Migrate basic slides');

    $source_fields = array(
      'nid' => t('The node ID of the slide'),
      'title' => t('The node title of the slide'),
      'uri' => t('the slide image'),
    );

    $q = db_select('node', 'n');
    $q->leftjoin('field_data_field_image', 'i', 'i.entity_id=n.nid');
    $q->leftjoin('file_managed', 'f', 'i.field_image_fid=f.fid');
    $q->fields('n', array('nid', 'vid', 'type', 'language', 'title', 'uid', 'status', 'created', 'changed', 'comment', 'promote', 'sticky', 'tnid', 'translate'))
      ->fields('f', array('uri'))
      ->condition('n.type', 'slide', '=');
    $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($q, $source_fields);


    $node_options = MigrateDestinationNode::options(LANGUAGE_NONE, 'filtered_html');
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('slide', $node_options);

    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
        array(
          'nid' => array(
            'type' => 'int',
            'unsigned' => TRUE,
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'description' => 'Unique Node ID',
            'alias' => 'n',
          )
        ),
        MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema()
    );

    $this->addFieldMapping('is_new')
      ->defaultValue(TRUE);

    $this->addFieldMapping('nid', 'nid');
    $this->addFieldMapping('title', 'title');
    $this->addFieldMapping('is_new')->defaultValue(TRUE);
    $this->addFieldMapping('uid', 'uid');
    $this->addFieldMapping('revision')->defaultValue(TRUE);
    $this->addFieldMapping('revision_uid', 'uid');
    $this->addFieldMapping('created', 'created');
    $this->addFieldMapping('changed', 'changed');
    $this->addFieldMapping('status', 'status');
    $this->addFieldMapping('promote', 'promote');
    $this->addFieldMapping('sticky', 'sticky');
    $this->addFieldMapping('comment', 'comment');
    $this->addFieldMapping('language')->defaultValue('und');

    $this->addFieldMapping('path')->issueGroup(t('DNM'));
    $this->addFieldMapping('pathauto_perform_alias')->defaultValue('1');

    $this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'name');
    $this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'vid');
    $this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'type');
    $this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'language');
    $this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'tnid');
    $this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'translate');

    $this->addFieldMapping('field_image', 'uri')
      ->arguments(FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
  }
}
```

I end up with this error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'map.destid1' in 'field list':
>   SELECT n.nid AS nid, n.vid AS vid, n.type AS type, n.language AS
>   language, n.title AS title, n.uid AS uid, n.status AS status,
>   n.created AS created, n.changed AS changed, n.comment AS comment,
>   n.promote AS promote, n.sticky AS sticky, n.tnid AS tnid, n.translate
>   AS translate, f.uri AS uri, map.destid1 AS migrate_map_destid1,
>   map.needs_update AS needs_update FROM {node} n LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   {field_data_field_image} i ON i.entity_id=n.nid LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   {file_managed} f ON i.field_image_fid=f.fid LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   {migrate_map_mtest} map ON n.nid = map.sourceid1 WHERE (n.type =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (map.sourceid1 IS NULL OR
>   map.needs_update = 1) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => slide
>   ) in MigrateSourceSQL->rewind()

Comment: Did you clear caches before you ran? Have you changed the destination or the key at all? Is Migrate the best option for this?

Answer (score 3):

This post about [Unknown column 'destid1' in 'field list'](https://drupal.org/comment/5977734#comment-5977734) helped me when I had the same problem.

In particular, drop the `migrate_map_*` and `migrate_message_*` tables since they may have been created incorrectly beforehand.

Comment: Also if you want to do `Updates` to content in Migrate > 2.5 (for example Migrate 2.6) you can supply `$options['track_changes'] = TRUE;` for any `MigrateSource` class. More about that here: http://timonweb.com/using-hash-value-trackchanges-to-detect-source-data-changes-in-migrate-for-drupal-7

Comment: The link in the previous comment moved to https://timonweb.com/posts/using-hash-value-track_changes-to-detect-source-data-changes-in-migrate-for-drupal-7/